# Are stored procedures in Cosmos DB automatically retried on conflict?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Stored procedures in Cosmos DB are transactional and run under isolation snapshop with optimistic concurrency control. That means that write conflicts can occur, but they are detected so the transaction is rolled back.

If such a conflict occurs, does Cosmos DB automatically retry the stored procedure, or does the client receive an exception (maybe a HTTP 412 precondition failure?) and need to implement the retry logic itself?

Comment: Did you ever find anything concrete regarding this? I was wondering if I should be settings the `etag` when upserting a document in my sproc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running 100 instances of a stored procedures in parallel that would produce a write conflict by reading the a document (without setting `_etag`), waiting for a while and then incrementing an integer property within that document (again without setting `_etag`).

In all trials so far, no errors occurred, and the result was as if the 100 runs were run sequentially. So the preliminary answer is: yes, Cosmos DB automatically retries running an SP on write conflicts (or perhaps enforces transactional isolation by some other means like locking), so clients hopefully don't need to worry about aborted SPs due to conflicts.

It would be great to hear from a Cosmos DB engineer how this is achieved: retry, locking or something different?

Comment: Marked my own answer as accepted until someone else posts a more qualified answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that this isn't properly documented anywhere. Here's how OCC check can be done in a stored procedure:

```
function storedProcedureWithEtag(newItem)
{
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    if (!newItem) {
        throw 'Missing item';
    }

    // update the item to set changed time
    newItem.ChangedTime = (new Date()).toISOString();
    var etagForOcc = newItem._etag;

    var upsertAccecpted = collection.upsertDocument(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        newItem,
        { etag: etagForOcc },       // <-- Pass in the etag
        function (err2, feed2, options2) {
            if (err2) throw err2;

            response.setBody(newItem);
        }
    );

    if (!upsertAccecpted) {
        throw "Unable to upsert item. Id: " + newItem.id;
    }
}
```

Credit: https://peter.intheazuresky.com/2016/12/22/documentdb-optimistic-concurrency-in-a-stored-procedure/

Answer (score -1):

SDK does not retry on a 412, 412 failures are related to [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control) and in those cases, you are controlling the ETag that you are passing. It is expected that the user handles the 412 by reading the newest version of the document, obtains the newer ETag, and retries the operation with the updated value.

- [Example for V3 SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L683-L772)
- [Example for V2 SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/master/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L404-L500)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer the question. I know how to handle 412 failures, but the question is: suppose you run a stored procedure that reads a document and after a delay writes a property (without ETag), and you have a second stored procedure that runs concurrently that reads the same document and after a delay writes another property (without ETag). What happens? Are the two runs scheduled in such a way that both procedures run succesfully (but as isolated transactions) or does one of them fail?

Comment: If you do concurrent writes to the same document, without Etag / Optimistic Concurrency, then whoever lands last is the one that defines the content of the document because these are complete Replace operations (there are no partial update support). They don't fail. 412 only happens if you are using ETag.

Comment: Sure, but if a document is read or written within a SP, the server will implicitly use ETag or some other document versioning property to do OCC under the hood. The question was whether the conflict causes the SP to abort, forcing the client to deal with failure (like in SQL Server with Snapshot Isolation), or whether Cosmos DB handles the failure transparently. My experiments so far suggest the latter.

Comment: I haven't found any indication that a Sproc creates implicit Optimistic Concurrency. I made the test of creating a Sproc that does an upsert on an existing document and called it concurrently with different values. All concurrent executions succeeded and the document's content was just the latest to complete execution.

Comment: The official doc says that Cosmos DB Sprocs run under Snapshot Isolation, which usually implies some form of OCC. Unfortunately, the precise semantics and guarantees are not documented. :-(